# Keyboard randomly writes on its own

Tags: keyboard, virus, malware

My friend gave me one of his old gaming keyboards a while ago. It works fine but sometimes it randomly types words like "tseries" or "spontttttt". It also likes to press Escape or Enter for no reason. This only happens when the keyboard is plugged in and does not seem to have anything to do with the buttons I press. I messaged him but he says he doesn't know whats going on (Not sure if thats the truth tho).

Does anyone know how I can fix this because it really annoys me sometimes...
thanks in advance

Comment: what make and model keyboard is this?  I would bet money it has some macro functionality, which is causing the issue.

Comment: Some keyboards can store keystrokes on the keyboard (without recourse to drivers). I had a very old Gateway Anykey OEM keyboard that could do this. I note that "T" is often the chat key and perhaps the macro record feature was activated when the friend was typing, realized it wasn't actually registering in the chat window, and then pressed T repeatedly to open a chat window.

Comment: spilling sticky liquids on a keyboard can also lead to multiple keypresses due to the design of the keyboard matrix. I think "tseries" would be a remarkable coincidence though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't necessarily blame the keyboard. Try using another keyboard and see if it also exhibits the same behavior. I would guess either virus/malware or a ghost is doing it. T-series is the name of a huge chineese youtube channel, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's some sort of malware out there that does something stupid like type t-series.

Comment: it could be a catch-all type virus designed to search different brands to increase search engine presence of the companies. I'd say its software based as its highly unlikely OP has any hardware plugged in doing it (unless its an unencrypted wireless receiver, but even then OP would have to be personally targeted)